# Complex shapes in android

Tags: android

I want to make shapes in android like following images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here each text is a `TextView`, these are the three cases,

1. If I send only one text then view may like first image.
2. Three texts means view may like 2nd image.
3. Four texts means view may like 3rd image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

First image is circle with stroke red and solid yellow

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="circle">
<stroke android:color="@color/red" android:width="1dp" /> 
<solid android:color="@color/yellow" /> 
</shape>
```

Set this drawable as background of text view and set "12" as text of text view.

Comment: I want play with single shape for all these.. Is it possible?

Comment: I dont think so. You will need different drawables for these 3 different scenarios.